Add Swagger UI for user to test endpoints
This might look as a newbie question.
Is there a way to have Swagger User Interface in my project?
Is this possible in localhost?
I want to have a interface for the user to test my API to see is the data is being handled the correct way.

What language / framework did you use to develop your API? There are libraries (such as Springdoc for Java/Spring, or Swashbuckle.AspNetCore for ASP.NET) that can add Swagger UI to your API out of the box.


Download the swagger-ui HTML/JS project from the release branch https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases
Copy the contents of /dist folder of the zip file to tomcat/webapps directory
To show multiple APIs edit the swagger-initializer.js file as mentioned in the below link
Swagger UI with Multiple Urls
Access the UI http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/

if you are using any other web server the above still holds good
